# jmeter - Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, functional, email

I am new to jmeter and trying to send an email using SMTP.

Here is my sampler:

[image]

this is the error results:

```
Thread Name: REST example 1-3
Sample Start: 2018-01-15 14:34:54 CET
Load time: 21003
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 173
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 173
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Please how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try connecting to test connectivity to `smtp.gmail.com:587` using [telnet tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) or equivalent. If you cannot - it might be the case you're behind the corporate firewall and you'll need to "tell" JMeter to use your corporate proxy.

For [HTTP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) add the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
https.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
https.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
```

for SMTP set the [following property](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy):

```
socksProxyHost=your_proxy_host
```

You can also pass them to JMeter startup script via [-D command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -DsocksProxyHost=your_proxy_host
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.